# Sonata admin overwrite service configuration

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have the sonata admin bundle installed with the notifications bundle from the same vendor. However I don't want to display the notification bundle on the admin panel.

I know that, in order to do this, I can use:

```
show_in_dashboard="false"
```

I have placed it on the vendor folder and it works but I wanted to place it on the config.yml so it doesn't cause problems between server or version updates.

Any idea on how to do this?

For whom may care the normal syntax to disable the presentation is:

```
<tag
                    name="sonata.admin"
                    manager_type="orm"
                    group="sonata_notification"
                    label="notifications"
                    label_translator_strategy="sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore"
                    show_in_dashboard="false"
               />
```

or in yml:

```
tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Some Group", label: "", show_in_dashboard: false }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I solve this problem is by specifying explicitly in sonata_admin config which admin services to display in dashboard.

```
sonata_admin:
dashboard:
    blocks:
        # display a dashboard block
        - { position: left, type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list }

    groups:
        some_group:
          label:  "Some group"
          items:
            - some_admin_service
            - some_other_admin_Service
        some_other_group:
          label:  "Some other group"
          items:
            ...
```

Some more examples can be found in documentation http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-1/doc/reference/dashboard.html

Answer (score 1):

You can override services definition using services.yml (in your case).

1) Create file (if it not exists): app/config/services.yml

2) In config.yml in section "imports" add new source:

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }
```

3) Add service definition with

```
show_in_dashboard: false
```

It'll override defaults from vendor